# Context injection in SpecFlow: how to avoid "BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Primitive types or structs cannot be resolved"?

Tags: c#, specflow

Using SpecFlow, I want to share data between bindings using Context Injection, but I don't know how to avoid "BoDi.ObjectContainerException: 'Primitive types or structs cannot be resolved" exceptions when some instance cannot be resolved.

I have been using ScenarioContext and FeatureContext to share data between bindings, but with SpecFlow 3 these methods are obsolete (the following warning message is displayed "ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete: Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection"). So, I started using Context Injection.

I am adding an object instance to the container:

```
private readonly IObjectContainer myInstance;

public CommonSteps(IObjectContainer myInstance)
{
   this.myInstance = myInstance;
}

[When(@"I click on the dropdown")]
public void WhenIClickOnTheDropdown(string dropdown)
{       
   MyClass myElement = ...
   myInstance.RegisterInstanceAs(myElement);
}
```

And then in another binding class I am getting that instance:

```
private readonly MyClass myInstance;

public MetadataConfigurationSteps(MyClass myInstance)
{
    this.myInstance = myInstance;
}
```

The problem is that I don't need myInstance in every step of this binding class. I have tests in which myInstance is not initialized, because I don't need it, and so I will get the "BoDi.ObjectContainerException: 'Primitive types or structs cannot be resolved" exception.

So, how can I avoid this exception? Do I always need to add myInstance to the container even that I will not need it after? Or should I refactor my MetadataConfigurationSteps class so I only have there steps that use myInstance?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with adding an object to the container if it is not used in every step. Just keep it simple for yourself and add it to the container in a `[BeforeScenario]` hook.